# Closing Libuv Loop Correctly During Initialization

Tags: c, libuv, resource-cleanup

I am initializing a loop in libuv, but if I need to return after I initialized the loop but before I have called `uv_run`, how do I correctly clean up all memory and file descriptors? Here is my example code, `loop` being `uv_loop_t*` and `server` being `uv_tcp_t*`:

```
if (uv_loop_init(loop) < 0) {
    return -1;
}
if (uv_tcp_init(loop, server) < 0) {
    // What code here?
    return -1;
}
if (some_other_function() < 0) {
    // What code here?
    return -1;
}
uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615340/closing-libuv-handles-correctly), I should stop, walk and run the loop, closing all the handles; but that assumes I'm already running the loop, which I'm not. I could just call `uv_loop_close(loop)`, but that doesn't free the handles.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link, you need to do something like this;

```
uv_loop_init(&loop);
uv_tcp_init(&loop, &server);

uv_walk(&loop,
              [](uv_handle_t* handle, void* arg) {
                  printf("closing...%p\n", handle);
                  uv_close(handle, [](uv_handle_t* handle) {
                             printf("closed...%p\n", handle);
                             }
                          );
                  uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_ONCE);
                  },
        NULL);
```